# Pre/post increment with #define in c

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pre-increment

I wrote a small piece of code in which I used #define with increment operator. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define square(a) ((a)*(a))

int main ()
{
    int num , res ;
    scanf ("%d",&num ) ;
    res = square ( num++ ) ;
    printf ( "The result is %d.\n", res ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

But while compiling this in gcc, I got the following note and warning:

```
defineTest.c:8:20: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'num' [-Wunsequenced]
    res = square ( num++ ) ;
                      ^~
defineTest.c:2:21: note: expanded from macro 'square'
    #define square(a) ((a)*(a))
                        ^
1 warning generated.
```

Please explain the warning and note.
The output I got was :

> $ ./a.out
> 1
> The result is 2.
>
> $ ./a.out
> 2
> The result is 6.

Also explain how the code works.

Comment: Your `res` becomes `res = ((num++)*(num++)) ;` Read this :http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/1870232

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `square(num++)`

Comment: Invoking undefined behaviour — and maybe the thousandth question on the topic.  The only marginal novelty is the use of the preprocessor, but the result is exactly the same as all the others.

Comment: @P0W: the C++ question isn't the best way to guide C programmers.

Comment: My mantra: Almost Always Avoid Macros. (AAAM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro, after preprocessor expands it, will look like this:

```
((a++)*(a++))
```

Notice that, `a++` is the same as `a = a + 1`, so you can rewrite expanded macro as:

```
((a = a + 1)*(a = a + 1))
```

You are changing value of `a` (or `num`, to be exact) twice in one statement, which generates warning, as this is undefined behaviour.

I would suggest you to rewrite your macro as a function

```
int square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```